# Thread Blocking at Groovy ExpandoMetaclass method in a Grails App

Tags: performance, grails

We are load testing our Grails application (Grails 2.0 Version) hosted on Glassfish  3.1.1 App Server. While testing we are constantly getting thread blocked at ExpandoMetaClass' **performOperationOnMetaClass** method.   The stack trace is given. Is this is a known issue with Grails?

`"http-thread-pool-11180(427)" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002e1ec800 nid=0x1e90 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000006944c000]`

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at  groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.performOperationOnMetaClass(ExpandoMetaClass.java:809)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007d1ce8e88> (a groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.registerInstanceMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:873)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.setProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:788)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:179)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.filters.FilterConfig.methodMissing(FilterConfig.groovy:86)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor336.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:828)</code>
```

The stack trace is longer and eventually starts from org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib.captureTagContent(SitemeshTagLib.groovy). Anybody has come across these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailing list thread: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Thread-Blocking-at-Groovy-ExpandoMetaclass-method-in-a-Grails-App-td4572990.html